# Unit testing with Crosswalk and Robolectric

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric, crosswalk-runtime

We have unit tests running against our app, based on Robolectric. Some of these tests check against activities that contain WebViews.

Now we decided to use Crosswalk and, therefore, replace `WebView` with `XWalkView` in our layout XML files. But since then, the unit tests fail to run because Robolectric apparently doesn't support `XWalkView`s yet.

We tried writing a shadow for XWalkView, but Robolectric still calls the real implementation when inflating the content view. Other shadows (e.g. a custom WifiManager shadow) work correctly.

This is the stacktrace we encounter (code below):

```
android.view.InflateException: XML file build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/layout/activity_crosswalk.xml line #-1 (sorry, not yet implemented): Error inflating class org.xwalk.core.XWalkView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928)
    at mycompany.myapp.test.xwalkshadow.CrosswalkActivity.onCreate(CrosswalkActivity.java:11)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
    at org.robolectric.util.ReflectionHelpers.callInstanceMethod(ReflectionHelpers.java:195)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController$1.run(ActivityController.java:122)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:304)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.CoreShadowsAdapter$2.runPaused(CoreShadowsAdapter.java:45)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:118)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:129)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.setup(ActivityController.java:210)
    at org.robolectric.Robolectric.setupActivity(Robolectric.java:46)
    at mycompany.myapp.test.xwalkshadow.XWalkShadowRobolectricUnitTest.testInstantiation(XWalkShadowRobolectricUnitTest.java:19)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:251)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:188)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:54)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:152)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.$$robo$$inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.$$robo$$setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java)
    at android.app.Activity.$$robo$$setContentView(Activity.java:1928)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java)
    at mycompany.myapp.test.xwalkshadow.CrosswalkActivity.onCreate(CrosswalkActivity.java:11)
    at android.app.Activity.$$robo$$performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.robolectric.util.ReflectionHelpers.callInstanceMethod(ReflectionHelpers.java:195)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController$1.run(ActivityController.java:122)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:304)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.CoreShadowsAdapter$2.runPaused(CoreShadowsAdapter.java:45)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:118)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:129)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.setup(ActivityController.java:210)
    at org.robolectric.Robolectric.setupActivity(Robolectric.java:46)
    at mycompany.myapp.test.xwalkshadow.XWalkShadowRobolectricUnitTest.testInstantiation(XWalkShadowRobolectricUnitTest.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:251)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:188)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:54)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:152)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Please have your activity extend XWalkActivity for shared mode
    at org.xwalk.core.XWalkCoreWrapper.initEmbeddedMode(XWalkCoreWrapper.java:189)
    at org.xwalk.core.XWalkView.reflectionInit(XWalkView.java:761)
    at org.xwalk.core.XWalkView.<init>(XWalkView.java:221)
    ... 63 more
```

This is the activity to be tested:

```
package mycompany.myapp.test.xwalkshadow;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class CrosswalkActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_crosswalk);
    }
}
```

This is the layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="mycompany.myapp.test.xwalkshadow.CrosswalkActivity">

    <org.xwalk.core.XWalkView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </org.xwalk.core.XWalkView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the unit test code:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.robolectric.Robolectric;
import org.robolectric.RobolectricGradleTestRunner;
import org.robolectric.annotation.Config;

@Config(
        sdk = 19,
        constants = BuildConfig.class,
        shadows = ShadowXWalkView.class
)
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
public class XWalkShadowRobolectricUnitTest {
    @Test
    public void testInstantiation() {
        Robolectric.setupActivity(CrosswalkActivity.class);
    }
}
```

This is the simple shadow for XWalkView:

```
package mycompany.myapp.test.xwalkshadow;

import org.robolectric.annotation.Implements;
import org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowViewGroup;
import org.xwalk.core.XWalkView;

/**
 * Created by enrico on 14/12/15.
 */
@Implements(value = XWalkView.class, callThroughByDefault = false, isInAndroidSdk = false)
public class ShadowXWalkView extends ShadowViewGroup {
}
```

And this is the relevant part in `build.gradle` about Crosswalk and Robolectric:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0"
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric-annotations:3.0-rc3'
}

// Crosswalk
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:15.44.384.12'
}
```

Any hint is highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I think something wrong with shadowing. But lets wait for guys who experienced in writing them. Is your shadow in classpath for tests?

Comment: Yes it is. It's true that the stack trace looks very similar to the one I got when there was no shadow at all. But I can tell Robolectric is using my shadow because if I let it extend `ShadowView` instead of `ShadowViewGroup` I get a different exception.

Comment: @ris8_allo_zen0, did you ever get this working?

Comment: Nope, we abandoned the idea of testing on Crosswalk and focused on other aspects.