# Error using PowerMock and Roboletric to mock a custom View

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, robolectric, powermock

I want to unit-test the behaviour of an `Activity` whose content view contains a custom, non-Android `View`, using Robolectric. So I want to mock that view.

I tried with Mockito, but the custom view is instantiated by the `LayoutInflater` system service using `Class.newInstance`; moreover, that specific part of code is inside a final method. So Mockito can't help me in this issue.

PowerMock seemed to me to be a viable solution because of its class-loader "magic" that may intercept the construction of the custom view I want to mock; however, a basic unit test that doesn't even test anything, nor create the test Activity, like

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 21)
@PowerMockIgnore({ "org.mockito.*", "org.robolectric.*", "android.*" })
@PrepareForTest({View.class, CustomView.class})
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class PowerMockAndRobolectricUnitTest {

    @Rule
    public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

    @Test
    public void testInstantiation() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        CustomView mockCustomView = PowerMockito.mock(CustomView.class);
    }
}
```

(where `CustomView` is a custom view generated by Android Studio without any other change) leads to a run-time error in the `PowerMockito.mock` statement with this stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to transform class with name android.view.View. Reason: by javassist.bytecode.BadBytecode: getVerticalFadingEdgeLength ()I in android.view.View: failed to resolve types
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:267)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:180)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:70)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:270)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:180)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:70)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at mycompany.myapp.test.customview.PowerMockAndRobolectricUnitTest.testInstantiation(PowerMockAndRobolectricUnitTest.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement$1.run(PowerMockRule.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.performMethodInvocation(WhiteboxImpl.java:1873)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.doInvokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:773)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.invokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:638)
    at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeMethod(Whitebox.java:401)
    at org.powermock.classloading.ClassloaderExecutor.execute(ClassloaderExecutor.java:98)
    at org.powermock.classloading.ClassloaderExecutor.execute(ClassloaderExecutor.java:78)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement.evaluate(PowerMockRule.java:57)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:251)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:188)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:54)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:152)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: javassist.CannotCompileException: by javassist.bytecode.BadBytecode: getVerticalFadingEdgeLength ()I in android.view.View: failed to resolve types
    at javassist.CtBehavior.insertBefore(CtBehavior.java:777)
    at javassist.CtBehavior.insertBefore(CtBehavior.java:734)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.MainMockTransformer.modifyMethod(MainMockTransformer.java:197)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.MainMockTransformer.allowMockingOfStaticAndFinalAndNativeMethods(MainMockTransformer.java:133)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.MainMockTransformer.transform(MainMockTransformer.java:65)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:252)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: javassist.bytecode.BadBytecode: getVerticalFadingEdgeLength ()I in android.view.View: failed to resolve types
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:111)
    at javassist.bytecode.MethodInfo.rebuildStackMap(MethodInfo.java:440)
    at javassist.bytecode.MethodInfo.rebuildStackMapIf6(MethodInfo.java:422)
    at javassist.CtBehavior.insertBefore(CtBehavior.java:768)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: javassist.bytecode.BadBytecode: failed to resolve types
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:169)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:108)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: javassist.NotFoundException: android.view.View$ScrollabilityCache
    at javassist.ClassPool.get(ClassPool.java:452)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.TypeData$TypeVar.fixTypes2(TypeData.java:347)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.TypeData$TypeVar.fixTypes(TypeData.java:330)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.TypeData$TypeVar.dfs(TypeData.java:274)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.fixTypes(MapMaker.java:390)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:167)
    ... 59 more
```

The problematic class seems `android.view.View.ScrollabilityCache`, a non-public class in Android API. But my real unit test (that mocks Crosswalk's XWalkView, as tried [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34270884/327648)) shows a different class, and the last "Caused by" stanza is replaced by

```
Caused by: javassist.NotFoundException: android.view.View$AttachInfo
    at javassist.ClassPool.get(ClassPool.java:452)
    at javassist.bytecode.Descriptor.toCtClass(Descriptor.java:592)
    at javassist.bytecode.Descriptor.getParameterTypes(Descriptor.java:439)
    at javassist.CtBehavior.getParameterTypes(CtBehavior.java:298)
    at javassist.CtBehavior.insertBefore(CtBehavior.java:749)
    ... 62 more
```

This makes me think that the error is somewhere in Powermock, either in the way I'm using it (it's the first time for me) or in the implementation.

This is my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mycompany.myapp.test.xwalkshadow"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0"
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric-annotations:3.0-rc3'

    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.4"
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:1.6.4"
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.4"
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-classloading-xstream:1.6.4"
}
```

Any hint about how to successfully mock a custom view, referenced by an XML layout file, with PowerMock and Robolectric?